# How to find intensity from TextBlob sentiment analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am using the sentiment analysis tool in the TextBlob package on Python 3.7. I am familiar with it and [understand that it works on a basis of 3 values](https://planspace.org/20150607-textblob_sentiment/): polarity, subjectivity, and intensity. Polarity and subjectivity are standard output from `TextBlob('string').sentiment`, however `TextBlob('string').intensity` was sadly not successful. Any clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to calculate the intensity in textblob library.

1) Please refer to line 439 of the source code for the sentiment function: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py

It provides an option to calculate polarity and subjectivity but, there is no argument for intensity.

2) If we talk about separate functions (mentioned by you), it is also not available in the source code.

3) The following link provides and shows that intensity and confidence are included but the source code lacks the function.

https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/eb08c120d364e908646731d60b4e4c6c1712ff63/textblob/en/en-sentiment.xml

Comment: Thank you for your help. I suppose I will have to change my code a little then!